# 'This webpage is not available' after 'shutdown -r now'

Tags: shutdown, amazon-ec2

I've been having some MySQL issues so I tried to restart my server with `shutdown -r now`. I can SSH into it, but any page I try to navigate to now returns:

> ```
> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> Google Chrome's connection attempt to xxx.amazonaws.com was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
> ```

What can I do to bring it back online?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to start with looking at the aws page for the instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your webserver and maybe your database did not start with the os.
You need to check if they are running and start them manually if they aren't.

Starting Apache HTTPD and MySQL in CentOS/RHEL:

```
service mysql start
service httpd start
```

And in ubuntu/debian:

```
service mysql start
service apache2 start
```